# Google Firebase - Phone Authentication results Error on some phones

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Google Firebase for Phone Number Verification in iOS (Swift) App.
At Every Step I have logged status at my end. Same process works for most, but results error on some devices with No possible information on why its doing like this.

On Most of the process works **Fine**.
FCM Fake Token for Verification is received -> Firebase results with success. SMS is received & Verified.

On Some Phones the process works **Wrong**.
FCM Fake Token for Verification is received -> Firebase results with error -> SMS is NOT received.

Error says "There seems to be a problem with your project's Firebase phone number authentication set-up, please make sure to follow the instructions found at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth"

Comment: Could you share the code for phone number verification? It would be helpful to see where the error is logged. Also, it mentions in the documentation that the phone must have push notifications consent. Older devices need not obtain consent for the silent push notifications, so this may be the issue for some phones working or not.

Comment: Any commonality of model, area code or OS version with the failing devices?

Comment: It happens on some phone. At our office we have 10 iOS phones. One has this issue. We reinstalled it many times on that phone. Never worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried switching the sim cards? Just as a debugging step, swap the sim cards between a phone that didn't receive the SMS and one that did. That way, you can tell if the problem is related to your Firebase setup (which I think is unlikely) or the network.

I had an issue where I had my number on a marketing opt-out list, which as a side effect caused several of these kinds of verification SMS messages to be blocked as well. That's one example, but there could be other reasons the network is blocking an SMS as well.

Comment: The problem is not at the receiving end. The message is not sent from Firebase and error is received from the Firebase on Sender side. This happens on Users side so sim swapping is not possible.

Comment: 'Firebase results with error' means SMS is NOT Sent.

Comment: Secondly the comment needs revision as the question explicitly mentions, 'iOS (Swift) App'

Comment: Actually, the message in your post says "SMS is NOT *received*". Switching the SIM cards was a way to help debug why the SMS is not *received*.

Comment: About the Android comment: It's been two days and I didn't read the post again. Simple mistake.